# What kind of mushroom is this, and is it edible?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

[image: Top view][image: Side view][image: Turned over 1][image: Turned over 2][image: Turned over 3]

I found these growing on the side of some trees (mostly birch) in my local forest in Gothenburg, Sweden, and was wondering if you could help me with identifying them.

I think they smell of aniseed however my wife thinks they smell of farm animals!

The spore-trace turned out white, if that aids with identification.

Comment: Might be oyster mushrooms; look them up. Generally one learns to identify some edible mushrooms and then looks for them. Picking mushrooms and then trying to determine if they are edible is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the help blacksmith37. Just out of curiosity, why is that not recommended? And by whom is it not recommended? I've always found it more helpful to learn identification with a specimen at hand.

Comment: I have several "mushroom" guides , don't remember which ones said it. Pick and examine them with the prospect that the same species may come back in the same spot when you are very familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks blacksmith37, I shall keep that in mind. The spore-trace turned out white, so I think you may be right in calling the oyster mushroom.